# Advanced webscraper

Tags: python, web-scraping

I need to use web scraper in python, but I don't know which will allow me for complete following tasks (if even it's possible):

- open page from link
- login on it
- fill one of the text fields with some string
- click on the search button
- parse the result page for geting specific info

I have already written script with selenium but it's bad solution for me. I need sth. more stable, and also selenium is not created for such task like creating some kind of database.

Comment: 1. Selenium is not "stable" only if your code is not good. 2. None of web-scraping tools is created for such tasks as creating databases...

Answer (score 1):

You can use several things.

Selenium, webkit from inside of your UI library of choice (I've used pyQt.webkit) with some javascript injection, or scrapy.

They're all perfectly valid options.